# Java update SQL database SQL error?

Tags: java, sqlite

```
     try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.
        prepareStatement(
        "update klant set naam = ?, voornaam = ?, geboortedatum = ?, opmerking = ?, debetstand_limiet = ?, actief = ? from klant where id = ?");) {

        stmt.setString(1, teWijzigenKlant.getNaam());
        stmt.setString(2, teWijzigenKlant.getVoornaam());
        stmt.setString(3, teWijzigenKlant.getGeboorteDatum().toString());
        stmt.setString(4, teWijzigenKlant.getOpmerking());
        stmt.setDouble(5, teWijzigenKlant.getDebetstandLimiet().doubleValue());
        byte b;
        if (teWijzigenKlant.isActief() == true){
            b = 1;
        }
        else{
            b = 0;
        }
        stmt.setByte(6, b);
        stmt.setInt(7, teWijzigenKlant.getId());
        stmt.execute();
```

When I try to test a method that contains this code, it says I have an error in my SQL syntax but I can't seem to figure out what it is... My database consists of the following columns:

```
1   id  int(11)         Nee Geen    AUTO_INCREMENT  Veranderen Veranderen   
2   naam    varchar(64) latin1_swedish_ci       Nee Geen        Veranderen 
3   voornaam    varchar(32) latin1_swedish_ci       Nee Geen        
4   geboortedatum   date            Nee Geen        Veranderen Veranderen   
5   opmerking   text    latin1_swedish_ci       Ja  NULL        Veranderen 
6   debetstand_limiet   double          Nee Geen        Veranderen Veranderen   
7   actief  tinyint(1)
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 "update klant set [..snip..] from klant where id = ?");) {
                              ^^^^^^^^^^
```

`update` queries don't have a `from` clause... and would be redundant ANYWAYS since you already specified table `klant` at the beginning of the update string.

Comment: Genius! Thank you, i'll accept your answer as soon as I can, it's immediatly fixed and I'm happy the rest of my code is working as intended. Thanks! :)